# Firefox setting “tabMinWidth” not working, how can I configure minimum tab width?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

When I install my computer, I like to set the tabs minimum width to a smaller value via the `about:config` page. I've noticed that this no longer works (I'm on 8.0), although the setting still exists. Shouldn't this still work?

**How can I make the tabs narrower than they presently are?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depreciated FF 4.0

> This pref has been removed as part of the Firefox 4.0 theme work. Users can now specify the tab width using css via UserChrome.css or use the Custom Tab Width extension.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.tabs.tabMinWidth

You can look into defining it by UserChrome.css [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.css)

Or just download the extension from the addons site [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/custom-tab-width/)

Comment: *Thank you,* I will grab the extension you suggest! I was not aware of the deprecated status, and I don't get why it's still in the about:config then...

Comment: I don't think its in there anymore (I don't have it in mine)
Perhaps its still there from when you modified it in an earlier version and the settings were kept between upgrades

Comment: Ah yes, it may be a remnant from an upgrade. I'll check on my newly installed machine at home.

Answer (score 2):

For userChrome.css, add:

```
.tabbrowser-tab:not([pinned])
{
  max-width: 150px !important;
  min-width: 10px !important;
}
.tabbrowser-tab:not([fadein])
{
 max-width: 1px !important;
 min-width: 1px !important;
 max-width: 1px;
 min-width: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) extension, you can use that to configure the tab width. There's a already a user style which does that really well: http://userstyles.org/styles/53019/firefox-5-minimal-browser-tab-width

Answer (score 0):

As of Firefox 71.0 (from January 2020), the `browser.tabs.tabMinWidth` config setting still exists and still works. You can edit it after entering `about:config` into the URL bar.

So maybe the [depreciation warning](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.tabs.tabMinWidth) about this config setting is itself outdated.